# edit_comment capability for subscriber

Tags: comments, capabilities

I have given my site's subscriber role the following permissions (unserialized DB-query):

```
[subscriber] => Array
    (
        [name] => Reader
        [capabilities] => Array
            (
                [delete_comment] => 1
                [edit_comment] => 1
                [level_0] => 1
                [quick_edit_comment] => 1
                [read] => 1
                [reply_comment] => 1
                [unfiltered_html] => 1
            )

    )
```

I want to make the subscriber be able to edit their comments, but I always get an error "Your are not allowed to edit this comment." I tried the following in debugging (in my comments.php template file):

```
$link = get_edit_comment_link($GLOBALS['comment']->comment_ID);
$perm1 = current_user_can('edit_comment', $GLOBALS['comment']->comment_ID);
$perm2 = current_user_can('edit_comment');
var_dump($link);
var_dump($perm1);
var_dump($perm2);
global $current_user;
var_dump($current_user->allcaps);
```

giving the following output (explanation added beside):

```
(get_edit_comment_link): NULL
(cur_user w/ post-id): bool(false)
(cur_user w/o post-id): bool(false)

(allcaps): 
array(9) { ["delete_comment"]=> bool(true) ["edit_comment"]=> bool(true) 
["edit_posts"]=> bool(true) ["level_0"]=> bool(true) ["quick_edit_comment"]=> bool(true) 
["read"]=> bool(true) ["reply_comment"]=> bool(true) ["unfiltered_html"]=> bool(true) 
["subscriber"]=> bool(true) }
```

As you can see, the allcaps shows that the user is allowed to edit_comments. But get_edit_comment_link stays empty, although the role has the capability AND the current_user is the author of the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```php
$subscriber= get_role('subscriber');
$subscriber->add_cap('edit_comment');
```

**NOTE**
`edit_comment` is only supported in verson 3.1 or later

This worked for me , hope it helps you!